# How to get live database change notifications in ASP.Net using MSSQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms

Im designing a logistics website in ASP.Net, customers are able to place order, orders will inserted to database. 
I want, when a new order inserted into database, it automatically send a notification to employee for new order.
the question is , how to manipulate the following code to get live notifications ,when database changes?

```
public class FreightOrderList
{

    int customerID = 0;

    public int CustomerID
    {
        get { return customerID; }
        set { customerID = value; }
    }
    string email = string.Empty;



    public FreightOrderList()
    {
        //default Cons
    }

    public FreightOrderList(int _customerID)
    {
        this.customerID = _customerID;

    }

    public DataSet displayOrders()
    {
        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LGDB"].ToString();
        SqlConnection sqlConnectionObj = new SqlConnection(ConString);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapterObj = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dataSetObj = new DataSet();
        sqlDataAdapterObj.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
        sqlDataAdapterObj.SelectCommand.Connection = sqlConnectionObj;
        sqlDataAdapterObj.SelectCommand.CommandText = "customerShipOrderProc";
        sqlDataAdapterObj.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlConnectionObj.Open();
        sqlDataAdapterObj.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("customerID", this.CustomerID);

        sqlDataAdapterObj.Fill(dataSetObj,"customerShipOrder");
        sqlConnectionObj.Close();
        return dataSetObj;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats a nice idea, but what was your question?

Comment: my question is what code should i write for that ?

Comment: Please make your question more clear. If I am right then , you need some Facebook type notification on web page, when some updates hits your account.

Comment: yea i want an automatic notification mechanism

Comment: Can I suggest you read [help/on-topic]

Comment: sorry if bad question i just join the site today

Comment: @AlirezaX , Please explain you question with some algorithms or code if you have. Or any exisiting reference would be a great help for both of us. Thats what here, everyone looking for. Otherwise your question will be either closed or deleted. Please update.

Comment: thanks remit , im writing the code , i will upload asap ,

Comment: @AlirezaX - Thats fine. I assumed you were pretty new to SO. Which is why I provided that specific link so you can start to understand the sort of questions welcomed here.

Comment: @Jamiec thank for suggesting the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sqldependency which updates you when a row is updated instead of hitting the database over and over again.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx

or

If you are skilled, you can go for Asynchronous Page or [SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)

or

AJAX Callbacks

Comment: @Alizerax , yes of course.See http://www.clientsideasp.net/2009/03/01/aspnet-ajax-poll-using-jquery-a-complete-implementation-with-admin-part/